# tasklist -v truncation of output

Tags: perl, tasklist

Evidently the Windows dos cmd "tasklist -v " is truncating lines after so many characters.
My perl program is reading in special command processes to compare against processes stored in my database. I am trying to make sure expected processes are running.

Unfortunately the script fails since one of my 50 or so processes is truncated by "tasklist -v".

Is there an alternative command?

Thanks,
Sammy

Comment: `TASKLIST /FO LIST`? `... /FO CSV`?

Answer (score 1):

Following code demonstrates usage of `tasklist /fo table` command as a pipe input for further processing

Tip: `help tasklist`

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $regex = qr/^(?<name>.*?)\s+(?<pid>\d+)\s+(?<session_name>\S+)\s+(?<session>\d+)\s+(?<mem>.*)/;

$^ = 'STDOUT_TOP';

open my $pipe, 'tasklist /fo table|';
    
/$regex/ && write for <$pipe>;

close $pipe;

$~ = 'STDOUT_BOTTOM';
write;

exit 0;

format STDOUT_TOP =
+----------------------------------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| Name                             | PID        | SessName | Session | Memory    |
+----------------------------------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
.

format STDOUT = 
| @<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<<< | @>>>>>>>>> | @<<<<<<< | @>>>>>> | @>>>>>>>> |
$+{name}, $+{pid}, $+{session_name}, $+{session}, $+{mem}
.

format STDOUT_BOTTOM =
+----------------------------------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
.
```

Output

```
+----------------------------------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| Name                             | PID        | SessName | Session | Memory    |
+----------------------------------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| System Idle Process              |          0 | Services |       0 |       8 K |
| System                           |          4 | Services |       0 |   7,452 K |
| Registry                         |        100 | Services |       0 |  28,664 K |
| smss.exe                         |        412 | Services |       0 |     368 K |
| csrss.exe                        |        552 | Services |       0 |   2,256 K |
| csrss.exe                        |        776 | Console  |       1 |   2,496 K |
| wininit.exe                      |        796 | Services |       0 |   1,420 K |
| winlogon.exe                     |        860 | Console  |       1 |   5,084 K |
| services.exe                     |        940 | Services |       0 |   5,964 K |
..............
| RuntimeBroker.exe                |       7392 | Console  |       1 |   8,604 K |
| dwm.exe                          |       1224 | Console  |       1 |  70,144 K |
| chrome.exe                       |      10580 | Console  |       1 | 103,584 K |
| svchost.exe                      |      12152 | Services |       0 |   7,496 K |
| LockApp.exe                      |       2620 | Console  |       1 |  39,392 K |
| RuntimeBroker.exe                |       3104 | Console  |       1 |  30,508 K |
| chrome.exe                       |        452 | Console  |       1 |  54,088 K |
| svchost.exe                      |       7460 | Services |       0 |   7,408 K |
| svchost.exe                      |       5744 | Services |       0 |  11,540 K |
♀+----------------------------------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| Name                             | PID        | SessName | Session | Memory    |
+----------------------------------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
| WmiPrvSE.exe                     |       6200 | Services |       0 |  10,612 K |
| perl.exe                         |       2520 | Console  |       1 |   8,948 K |
| tasklist.exe                     |       4808 | Console  |       1 |   8,940 K |
+----------------------------------+------------+----------+---------+-----------+
```

Comment: "TASKLIST -V /FO CSV"  works. No truncation occurs.